# Flag in new column in text equals Yes in one of multiple columns

Tags: r

I've got a large dataset with multiple flags already set up. Now I want to aggregate it to have an overall flag if it is flagged in one or more of the colums

For example, I have a mixture of columns: Product, Product ID and then Flag 1, Flag 2, Flag 3. Now my new column needs to say if there is a Y in either Flag 1,2 or 3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `base R` solution:

Reproducible data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = sample(c("something", "nothing", "Y", "anotherthing"), 20, replace = T),
  col2 = sample(c("nothing", "Y", "anotherthing"), 20, replace = T),
  col3 = sample(c("something", "nothing", "Y", "anotherthing", "yetanotherthing"), 20, replace = T))
```

First create a new column into which to place the `Flag` value:

```
df$Flag <- NA
```

Then, using `grepl` to match `Y` as well as `apply` and `paste`to collapse the rows into strings, identify those rows that contain `Y` and update `NA` by `Flag`:

```
df$Flag[which(grepl("Y", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")))] <- "Flag"
```

Result:

```
df
           col1         col2            col3 Flag
1       nothing anotherthing       something <NA>
2  anotherthing anotherthing               Y Flag
3       nothing            Y               Y Flag
4  anotherthing anotherthing         nothing <NA>
5  anotherthing            Y       something Flag
6     something anotherthing       something <NA>
7             Y            Y         nothing Flag
8  anotherthing            Y               Y Flag
9             Y      nothing         nothing Flag
10      nothing      nothing yetanotherthing <NA>
11 anotherthing anotherthing       something <NA>
12      nothing anotherthing               Y Flag
13            Y anotherthing    anotherthing Flag
14            Y anotherthing       something Flag
15    something      nothing               Y Flag
16 anotherthing            Y         nothing Flag
17    something anotherthing       something <NA>
18    something      nothing    anotherthing <NA>
19      nothing      nothing yetanotherthing <NA>
20 anotherthing      nothing         nothing <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all flag columns are of the same type as Y:

```
flags = c("Flag1","Flag2","Flag3")

df <- cbind(df,
            Y %in% df[,flags] %>% as.matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `rowwise`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d <- tribble(~id, ~flag1, ~flag2, ~flag3,
             1, "Y", "N", NA,
             2, "Y", "Y", "Y",
             3, NA,"N","N")
d
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id flag1 flag2 flag3
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 Y     N     <NA> 
#> 2     2 Y     Y     Y    
#> 3     3 <NA>  N     N

d %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(overallStatus = if_else(any(c(flag1, flag2, flag3) == "Y", na.rm = T), "Y", "N"))
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id flag1 flag2 flag3 overallStatus
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>        
#> 1     1 Y     N     <NA>  Y            
#> 2     2 Y     Y     Y     Y            
#> 3     3 <NA>  N     N     N
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>